# SQL statement for lookup row source is incompatible with the Web

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access-2010

I have a table person in `Ms Access`, with one of the field name as `fieldmanager`. I am trying to publish access to the web. I am running a web compatibility checker.

Web compatibility checker throws the following error

ACCWeb105012

Error text:    SQL statement for lookup row source is incompatible with the Web.

What it means:    The SQL statement for the row source of the indicated lookup field is either ill-formed or is incompatible with the Web for a variety of reasons, such as it includes an unsupported SQL operator.
 Microsoft says `Use the Lookup Wizard to re-create the lookup field.`

I don't see any point in re-creating the lookup field.

In the lookup wizard, i see `"Row-Source`" with an SQL Query

```
SELECT User.UserName FROM Users WHERE [UserGroup]='Manager' And Active=Yes ORDER BY Users.UserName;
```

What changes should I do here, I am confused.

Comment: Unless it's a typo here, your column references a different table. User should be plural (be sure to check SQL in Access' query window). Also, try braketing `[Active]` and using boolean values: `[Active]=True` or `[Active]=-1`.

Comment: @Parfait yes its a typo, do you know how to fix my issue.

Comment: If you place the query in the MS Access query window as if you are creating a new query, does an error emerge? Did you try above suggestions?

Comment: @Parfait no error the form works perfect

Comment: Again, did you change `[Active]` and the `Yes` value in any way?